# Python - var = var = var value

Tags: python, python-requests

Can you please help me out with this?

```
AdminServer = "putty.exe -ssh 1.1.1.1"
Server1 = "putty.exe -ssh 2.2.2.2"

Server = requests.get('example.com')
#this returns the server name (AdminServer or Server1...)
subprocess.Popen(Server)
```

When i run this i get:

```
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Probably because `subprocess.Popen` tries to open the command `AdminServer` (which is not a command) and not its value (`putty.exe -ssh 1.1.1.1`)

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Your post title is totally cryptic and unhelpful.

Comment: Also, [tag:var] tag is weird, given that Python is not one of the languages that has the `var` keyword.

Comment: 1. Use full URLs 2. `.get()` returns a Response object and no hostname even if that was the payload. 3. You don't run code from untrusted resources (HTTP without S is always untrusted) directly.

Comment: for starters, you can't requests.get "example.com" it throws a missing schema error. Beyond that the response object, if you actually got it ... when cast to a string is something like `<Response 200>` which is obviously not a program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary, not variables. If you have variable names, the way to get the variable contents is `evil`, and almost always there is a better way. In this case:

```
server_connection_commands = {
  "AdminServer": "putty.exe -ssh 1.1.1.1",
  "Server1": "putty.exe -ssh 2.2.2.2"
}
server = requests.get('http://example.com').text
subprocess.Popen(server_connection_commands[server])
```

Comment: @MatthewStory: Bleh, didn't look close enough and took OP's "this returns the server name" as true. Fixed. However, that's not his core problem - the question is about how to get from string `"Server1"` to the contents of variable `Server1` (which is an XY problem, with X being "I have variables").

Comment: @Amadan Your crystal ball really is something marvelous.